# String Pool related concept but confusing

Tags: java, string

Consider the following code with comments

```
public class Demo
{
    public static void main(String aa[])
    {
        String hello="Hello",lo="lo",hel="Hel";
        System.out.println(other.hello=="Hel"+lo); // returns false because new strings are created
        System.out.println(other.hello==hel+lo); // returns false, same reason i think. Comment if i am not correct
        System.out.println(other.hello=="Hel"+"lo"); // returns true, how ?
    }
}
class other
{
    static String hello="Hello";
}
```

The first prints false because new Strings are created before comparison (correct me if I am wrong). 
Second also prints false due to the same reason I think. But the third statement prints true. How this happens or what is the reason behind this ?

Comment: Because "Hel" and "lo" are constants, so `"Hel" + "lo"` is evaluated *at compile time*, and hence, is *exactly the same* as "Hello"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expression:

```
"Hel"+"lo"
```

is a [*constant expression*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#d5e30735), which means that it is evaluated at compile time. Therefore the expression has the exact same treatment as the explicit string literal

```
"Hello"
```

which, BTW, is just another example of a constant expression. Quoting [JLS §15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#d5e30735):

> Constant expressions of type String are always "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method `String.intern`.

Answer (score 0):

Every string in the program is given a matching key.

If after concatenation you create a string that matches the same string literal that was already present, then they both are equal and pointing to the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Answering *inline*.

```
public static void main(String aa[])
    {
        String hello="Hello",lo="lo",hel="Hel";
        System.out.println(other.hello=="Hel"+lo); // returns false because new string is created
        System.out.println(other.hello==hel+lo); // returns false, same reason. Right
        System.out.println(other.hello=="Hel"+"lo"); // returns true, because "hel" + "lo" will be resolved to "hello" during compile time. So, Since "Hello" has already been added to the String constants pool, the reference to the same will be used here.
    }
```